# Avoid printing passwords in Jenkins console

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have Jenkins stage which is calling a "GetVMPassword" function from library. The function returns credential and it will be used to login remote server. We dont want to print the "ssh command" and "calling a funtion command" and its reponse on stage logs. So we used `‘#!/bin/sh -e \n’` before every command. Because if we print, this could reveal the remote server credentials in the stage log. This was working when we don't use "parallel execution" block.

When we include "ssh command" and "calling a function command" inside "parallel execution" block, passwords are printed in stage logs.

How can we avoid printing in **stage logs** the library command and its response when we use "parallel execution" block ?

This is snippet of my stage and parallel execution block.
[image: StageLog]

Jenkins Version: 2.235.3

```
@Library ('MyLib_API') _
pipeline{
    agent {
        label 'master'
    }
    stages{
        stage('BuildAll'){
            steps{
                script{
                    def executions = APPSERVERS.split(',').collectEntries {APPS -> 
                        ["Execution ${APPS}": {
                            stage(APPS) {                                
                                        APP_USERNAME = "ubuntu"
                                        response = getPassword("${APPS}","${APP_USERNAME}")
                                        sh '#!/bin/sh -e \n' + "sshpass -p '${response}' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${APP_USERNAME}@${APPS} 'ls'"
                                        sleep 2
                                
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                    parallel executions
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

"getPassword" is the function in library used to get the vm password dynamically.
"APPSERVERS" values we are getting from Active choice parameters option.This has list of IP's of servers.

Please help me to hide those library commands and responses from stage logs.

**We have tried below options.**

1. Used `set +x`  and it is not worked for us.
2. Password masking plugin will not work. Since response from the command will get print for our case.
3. We tried routing all the execution of commands to file and tried fetching it from there. In this option, also while parsing the file logs are printed in stage logs.

Comment: This was answered (again) [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73385627/598141)

Comment: I have went through the given thread. Mask password plugin will be helpful for us. since response of the command also has cred which i don't want to print it. We are dynamically picking passwords from rest service, so we could not use files for us.

Comment: Can you use a secrets management tool here?

Comment: @IanW - The given thread has static password which got stored in files. For our case, passwords will keep change and it need to pulled dynamically using functions in library.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting your script with set +x, if not use password masking plugins
as mentioned here - https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-36007

Comment: Thanks for your reply. we tried `set +x` and it is not working. Also we tried other options which i updated in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use input to pass the credential and mask it in log.
Here is a detailed answer [stackoverflow credentials masking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71770076/jenkins-mask-password-exposes-the-secret-text-when-call-from-return-keyword/71881839#71881839)

you can use this as well it works for me.

```
    node('Node Name'){

  
  println('Please enter the username')
  def userName = input(
    id: 'userName', message: 'VPN Username', parameters: [
      [$class: 'hudson.model.TextParameterDefinition', defaultValue :'', name: 'Username',  description: 'Please enter your username']
    ])
  
  println('Please enter the password')
  def userPassword = input(
    id: 'userPassword', message: 'VPN Password', parameters: [
      [$class: 'hudson.model.PasswordParameterDefinition', defaultValue :'', name: 'Password',  description: 'Please enter your password']
    ])
  connectToClient = bat(returnStdout: true, script: 'start Forticlient connect -h v3 -u ' + userName+ ':' + userPassword)
  
  stage('Deploy (Test)'){
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'IH_IIS_JENKINS', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
     bat"msdeploy command"
    }
  }
  
}
```

Comment: This thread also talking about static password masking. In our case passwords are dynamically pulled using API/curl which was in library function. Password also keep changing every 15 mins. we can not use Jenkins built in credential field.

Comment: I would suggest you to go to the solution once. Although, you can directly call the function value in a variable and then mask the variable. Then limit the scope of variable and then destroy the variable once used.

Comment: Thank Aniket for your reply. We tried this options as well, we are able to skip printing passwords in console logs. But stage logs are exposing the commands and passwords.

Comment: updated the answer can you use this approach